# Convert array of objects to Array Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, arrays

Is there any possible way in angularJs to convert this array of objects:

```
[{"tickets":1,"month":"june","year":2016},{"tickets":2,"month":"june","year":2015},{"tickets":3,"month":"december","year":2015}]
```

to an array like this:

```
[['tickets', 'month','year'], [1, "june",2016],[3, "june",2015],[1, "december",2015]]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure, its pure javascript can handle

```js
var array1 = [{"tickets":1,"month":"june","year":2016},
     {"tickets":2,"month":"june","year":2015},
     {"tickets":3,"month":"december","year":2015}];

  var array2 = [['tickets', 'month','year']];

 array1.forEach(function(item){
   array2.push([item.tickets, item.month, item.year]);
 })
 
 console.log(array2);
```

**UPDATE**

More flexible way, adviced by [JK_Jha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2754029/jk-jha)

```js
var array1 = [{"tickets":1,"month":"june","year":2016},
         {"tickets":2,"month":"june","year":2015},
         {"tickets":3,"month":"december","year":2015}];

var array2 = [Object.keys(array1[0])];

array1.forEach(function(item){
     array2.push([item.tickets, item.month, item.year]);
 })

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Why are youu hardcoding this: var array2 = [['tickets', 'month','year']];

Comment: Because, I believe first array of `array2` will serve as some kind of titles for table or something

Comment: you could have just done Object.keys(array1[0]). Thats better

Comment: Sure, you right. It's looks more flexible. Thank you

Comment: use object keys to build sub arrays...still relying on hard coding result structure

Answer (score 1):

Approach using [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) and [`Array#concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) that doesn't rely on knowing any of the property names or hard coding resultant array structure

```js
let data = [{"tickets":1,"month":"june","year":2016},{"tickets":2,"month":"june","year":2015},{"tickets":3,"month":"december","year":2015}];

let res = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return acc.concat([acc[0].map((key) => curr[key])]);
}, [Object.keys(data[0])]);

console.log(res)
```